# Show an equation only has harmonic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I want to show
$$\begin{cases}
\Delta(\Delta u) - \nabla\cdot (\Delta u \cdot \nabla u)=0\\
\int \Delta u < \infty\\
\Delta u \ge0
\end{cases}$$
in $\mathbb{R}^2$ only has a solution such that $\Delta u =0$.

How would I approach this? I want to treat $\Delta u$ as a variable say $v$, but the thing is I don't know how to deal with $\nabla u$. Or maybe there is another way?

Can anyone give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you willing to make any assumptions about the global behavior of $u$, e.g. integrable, square integrable, bounded, polynomial growth?

Comment: Assuming $u$ behaves nicely, also assuming statement is stated correctly, was wondering how dimensionality comes to play or maybe its true for $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @HansEngler Oh yup I forgot the subharmonicity and the integrablity for $\Delta u$.

Comment: @BigM I am not sure, maybe it still holds for n dimensions. I just faced the case in 2 dimensions.